# Object appears jagged in final render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, shaders

When I try to render a glass material, in rendered view it looks good, but when rendered, I get this wavy effect and black outlines.

[image]
[image]

Polygon detail:

[image]

The scene is just a glass object with a glass material, background with a texture with a Diffuse shader and a lighting setup of two plane emissions.

- Glass: 4 levels of subdivision surface modifier.
- Background: 4 levels of subdivision surface modifier.
- 2 plane emissions, with no modifiers.
- 80 samples.

What is causing that and how can I fix it?

Here's [the file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32038) if anybody wants to explore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subsurf modifier on the glass object is disabled in the render.

Make sure the camera icon the subsurf modifier is selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The icon is selected, but the object renders as if it is not. I get the same result when I uncheck it, It renders as a low poly object regardless of the icon setting, pretty weird.

Comment: @Vladimir It's not selected at all for me in your file, but selecting it fixes it just fine.. Are you sure you have the right object selected?

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that. I selected the background instead, my mistake. Thanks.